# only select records that repear mysql

Tags: mysql

i have the following query

```
SELECT id
     , created_date 
     , longitude
     , latitude 
  FROM score s
 where s.mobile_user_id = 14299
   and latitude != 0 
   and created_date > '2018-10-01 12:00:00' 
   and speed_range_id > 1
 group  
    by latitude, longitude
 order 
    by id asc;
```

This returns the following result:

```
  ID        CREATED_DATE           LAT          LON
    8289173 2018-10-02 16:52:54 -100.40871983   20.56314546
    8991287 2018-10-07 18:06:37 -100.40879701   20.56899227
    9077533 2018-10-08 11:55:31 -100.39687493   20.57479211
    9077534 2018-10-08 11:55:31 -100.36075875   20.58076244
    9077535 2018-10-08 11:55:31 -100.37852743   20.60783806
    9077536 2018-10-08 11:55:31 -100.36473954   20.61464554
    9077537 2018-10-08 11:55:31 -100.36424849   20.61501740
    9077538 2018-10-08 11:55:31 -100.40951731   20.60529101
    9227761 2018-10-09 18:10:00 -100.40851908   20.61148848
    9227762 2018-10-09 18:10:00 -100.40545509   20.61769963
    9227763 2018-10-09 18:10:00 -100.38008197   20.61098901
    9227764 2018-10-09 18:10:00 -100.36462022   20.61464574
    9227765 2018-10-09 18:10:00 -100.34415272   20.61327334
    9227766 2018-10-09 18:10:00 -100.33583425   20.61397514
```

However, i would like to only select those records which have the same created_date more than once, like dates 2018-10-08 11:55:31  and 2018-10-09 18:10:00 in this example. How could i write my query to ignore the top 2 which don't repeat?

I tried by using having created_date > 1 but it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Remember floating point values can fluctuate a little from 0.0 so a +/- might be necessary here.

Comment: You have a GROUP BY clause, but no aggregating values. This is never going to end well. See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Since LAT & LON are different, having cannot work because your group is on LAT & LON.

Try this :

```
SELECT id, created_date ,longitude,latitude
FROM napify.score s
where s.mobile_user_id = '14299' and latitude != 0.00000000 and created_date > '2018-10-01 12:00:00' and speed_range_id > 1
and created_date in (select created_date from napify.score group by created_date having count(*) > 1)
group by latitude, longitude
order by id asc;
```